# vb.net inline function help using dispatchtimer.tick

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8.1

I have been trying to get the following Barcode reader program working on a windows phone.

I have followed the steps on the following website : http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Generating_and_scanning_barcodes_using_ZXing_on_Windows_Phone

and have converted it to vb.net but there is one line of code that seems to be giving me trouble.

The example on the site uses c# and the following block of code is the one I`m having trouble with

```
// This timer will be used to scan the camera buffer every 250ms and scan for any barcodes
    _scanTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _scanTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
    _scanTimer.Tick += (o, arg) => ScanForBarcode();
```

when this is converted to vb.net you get the following

```
' This timer will be used to scan the camera buffer every 250ms and scan for any barcodes
_scanTimer = New DispatcherTimer()
_scanTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)
_scanTimer.Tick += Function(o, arg) ScanForBarcode()
```

I am getting two errors both on the last line:

1. Public Event Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called    directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

if I add the RaiseEvent to the beginning of the line I then get the following error

_scanTimer' is not an event of 'PhoneApp2.Scan'

2. the ScanForBarcode() event produces the following error : Expression does not produce a value.

Any help on the above errors would be much appreciated as I am not sure what to do to rectify the errors.

Thanks
   Gareth

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AddHandler _scanTimer.Tick, Sub(o As Object, arg As EventArgs)
                               ScanForBarcode()
                            End Sub
```

Or to shorten it even more:

```
AddHandler _scanTimer.Tick, Sub(o As Object, arg As EventArgs) ScanForBarcode()
```

Events are added using a different pattern in vb.net.

Comment: 'AddHandler' or 'RemoveHandler' statement event operand must be a dot-qualified expression or a simple name.

Comment: Sorry, Corrected the example.  I missed that ScanForBarCode doesn't use the standard event signature.

Comment: now the following error :Lambda parameter 'e' hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression.

Comment: You may have to change the names of `sender` and `e` in the anonymous method of the event handler depending on where you are putting the code.  The new names won't matter, as long as they don't try to hide any existing variables in scope.  Perhaps `o` and `arg` as in the original C#; sample is updated.